# Linking issue with QtCreator and CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, qt-creator

I'm new to QtCreator and CMake, and I can't figure why the following set up gives me an "unresolved external symbol".

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

@ixSci That Find_package(opengl) is there but I suppose it's not needed.. this is the cleaner cmakelists I have now:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

include_directories(../../glfw/glfw-2.7.7/include)    
link_directories(../../glfw/glfw-2.7.7/lib-msvc110)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opengl32 glfw)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you include all libraries and linked to them?

Comment: Hm.. I was thinking so. Am I not doing that with the link_directories and target_link_libraries? or is there still something missing?

Comment: Well, try that first. What IDE are you using?

Comment: have you tried to regenerate the project? Try to link with gldwdll if you have defined GLFW_DLL

Comment: if by regenerating the project you mean clean and rebuild, then yea. Tried it, same result. :\

Comment: @bash.d ... QtCreator

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of QtCreator...

Comment: @Rui did you link to glfwdll.lib??

Comment: Try to re-run the CMake from menu Build -> Run CMake. You could also try to first delete the CMakeCache.txt file from the build folder.

Comment: Is the lib you are trying to link build using mingw which comes with Qt Creator?

Comment: @Lap Don't think so, I think it's using msvc10. At least that's the only compiler that's listed on Compilers tab (as auto-detected).

Comment: @kullero Tried it. Still get the same error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing static and dynamic linking. You have to choose to use either of these.

When you use `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfwdll)` you are using dynamic linking, i.e. linking against dll version of the library. In that case you should place the GLFW.dll file same folder with the built executable to be able to run the program. It seems also that using the dll version of the library requires the flag `GLFW_DLL`defined. It would be better to define that in CMake using `add_definitions(-DGLFW_DLL)` rather than put it to source files.

Static linking is easier to handle, just use `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)`. You don't need the files `GLFWDLL.lib` and `GLFW.dll`.

So, with dynamic linking your`CMakeLists.txt` could look something like below (remove the `#define GLFW_DLL` from your source files).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
include_directories(../../glfw/glfw-2.7.7/include)    
link_directories(../../glfw/glfw-2.7.7/lib-msvc110)

add_definitions(-DGLFW_DLL)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opengl32 glfwdll)
```

And if you want to change to static linking, just change the last three rows to

```
#add_definitions(-DGLFW_DLL)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opengl32 glfw)
```

Hope it helps! All the code above is untested :-)

Comment: I can get the static linking to work, but I'm still having a hard time to use the dynamic libraries :S. Even with all that I keep getting that "exited with code -1073741515" error.

Comment: Did you copy the GLFW.dll to the directory where your executable is built?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GLFW is some open source library for OpenGL. So you are trying to find it by using `find_package(opengl)` but it is wrong. GLFW is not part of OpenGL. You need to apply some other approach, for example download some 3rdpart GLFW finder for cmake. [One](http://code.google.com/p/assembly3d/source/browse/tools/viewer/cmake/FindGLFW.cmake?spec=svnd1f903929efb04f6802f4057e92e853f8e6519b4&r=d1f903929efb04f6802f4057e92e853f8e6519b4) I've found. You need to download it, store somewhere(e.g. in your source tree) then add this path to the cmake `SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "YOUR_PATH_GOES_HERE")` at the top of your cmake file.
After you have done it you can use `FIND_PACKAGE(GLFW REQUIRED)` and use `${GLFW_LIBRARY}` in your `target_link_libraries`

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way to use third party libraries in CMake projects. But also the approach Rui is using should work.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested by bash.d I've tried using:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfwdll)
```

But I got this error:

> Starting E:\opengl\test\test.exe... 
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   E:\opengl\test\test.exe exited with code -1073741515

So then I tried using:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
```

But this time I've removed the `#define GLFW_DLL` and it worked.

Not sure why.

If somebody could explain how to properly use the glfwdll.lib, and why I couldn't use it, that would be great.

Thanks everyone.